# Error encountered in an inherited object inside a object in a API REST

Tags: api, rest, entity-framework-core

I have 2 API REST methods namely

```
OvertimeRequests/LIST 
SuspensionRecommendations/LIST
```

These method are using separate Tables/Stored Procs/ API
but both methods are using the `Approvers` list object which is a List of Users that approve the request which is from a single Table/Stored Proc/API

These methods work fine if the `Approvers` is not included. But once it is and I sent a request to the two methods simultaneously, I encounter this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.DateTime'

It is not a simple Invalid Cast Exception because I found out that the method that throws this error is the 2nd method that I call. For instance,

I call `OvertimeRequests/LIST` first, then  `SuspensionRecommendations/LIST` throw this error
and if I call `SuspensionRecommendations/LIST` first, then `OvertimeRequests/LIST` throw this error.

I cannot find anything that could help me.

I don't know if it is a API or Database issue. I am using ASP.NET Core - EntityFrameWork as my api and SQL as my database. TIA

Comment: We're gonna need a little more info:  1) OvertimeRequests Entity Model, 2) SuspensionRecommendations Entity Model, 3) Approvers Entity Model, 4) The code in your API methods, 5) The code that actually retrieve the data (if separate from the API methods).

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my error with this:

I created a new Object List for `SuspensionRecommendations/LIST` with the same properties and the same Stored Procs/Table.

I haven't encountered any error since then. I don't know. Maybe it is only an issue to EF perhaps.